# Нужна или не нужна запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна или нет запятая, совы?

`Не хотите(,) – никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли? – чтобы по-Леопольдовому, или по-леопольдовски, Вам же то, или Вам же-с, сделалось предложение-распредложение?`

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148653/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна:

*Не хотите, – **никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли?** – чтобы по-Леопольдовому, или по-леопольдовски, Вам же то, или Вам же-с, сделалось предложение-распредложение?*

За основу при анализе возьмем **упрощенный** вариант предложения (это не повлияет на решение):

*Не хотите, – **никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли?** – чтобы по-Леопольдовски вам же (= для вас) сделалось (мною) предложение.*

Перед первым тире ставится **запятая,** если этого требует структура **первой части** основного предложения (или **всего** предложения при необходимости): запятая ставится после **главного** предложения, далее вставка и придаточное предложение. Без запятой структура заданного СПП **не будет обозначена.**

В качестве образца использовано предложение **[из ПАС под ред. Лопатина, § 97](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)**

Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания следует отличать **от сочетания запятой и тире,** необходимого **по условиям контекста:**  *Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, **— живы ли, здоровы ли они? —** как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах* (А. Т.).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148654/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Это не по правилам. Из-за того, что место занято знаком вопроса, запятая никуда не переносится.

Comment: Почему вы не ответили про предложение РАН без запятой? Всё дело в том, что там единый знак не подходит, как и в предложении из вопроса.