# Не уверен в запятой и двух тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция

Когда-то давно Леопольд-мэтр задавал [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475153/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5) о предложении:

***Не хотите(,) — никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли? — чтобы по-Леопольдовому, или по-леопольдовски, Вам же то, или Вам же-с, сделалось предложение-распредложение?***

Sharon пишет, что указанная запятая нужна, но я в этом не уверен. Здесь с помощью тире обособлена вставная конструкция (*никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли?*), которая принадлежит **первой части предложения** (*не хотите*). Я имею в виду то, что не может быть запятой перед первым тире, даже если ее требует запятая из второй части, т. к. вставка относится к первой части (а поставив запятую перед ней, мы ее от этой первой части отделяем), т. е. запятая должна быть перед вторым тире, то есть стоять **после вставки**.

Но как запятую поставить перед вторым тире, если там уже стоит вопросительный знак? Запятую из-за вопроса поставить нельзя, перед первым тире тоже нельзя (почему — написано выше), но запятую нужно же где-то поставить? Как же тогда поступить? В таком случае, мне кажется, это оформление некорректно, т. к. некуда ставить нужную запятую, и нужно оформить в виде скобок:

***Не хотите (никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли?), чтобы по-Леопольдовому, или по-леопольдовски, Вам же то, или Вам же-с, сделалось предложение-распредложение?***

А как считаете вы? Возможно ли оформление с тире? Если да, куда ставить запятую? Или же с тире и правда некорректно оформлять? Расскажите в ответе, совы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант следует оформить по образцу **из ПАС под ред. Лопатина** [§ 97.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)

*Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, — **живы ли, здоровы ли они?** — как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах* (А. Т.).

Если запятую нельзя перенести из-за **вопросительного знака**, то ее нужно **оставить** на месте.

Убрать запятую совсем мы не можем, иначе структура предложения **не будет обозначена.**

Два тире мы ставим в том случае, если на месте вставки **не было** знаков. В заданном предложении (без вставки) **запятая** ставится перед союзом ЧТОБЫ.

Comment: Там, однако, – в ПАС – есть тоже пример похожий, где нет запятой.

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#. (Самый конец второго абзаца с начала. Там нет запятой, хотя есть *но*.)

Comment: Даже ПАС об этом не так, как мы, подумали! Мы – совы!

Comment: Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё не попадается (Щерб.).  И куда он запятую дел? Мог бы и поставить, союз НО все-таки.

Comment: Да, какой-то несовёнок.

Comment: Авторы текста – это художники слова, в том числе его графического оформления.  Графика вполне на уровне в обоих предложениях, так что совам остается думать и объяснять.  Я думаю вот что: может, союз НО и так достаточно выразителен,  читатели поймут грамматику без лишних знаков.

Answer (score 1):

Я поддерживаю Sharon, тоже считая, что запятая должна быть перенесена, а не съедаться знаком вопросительным (или восклицательным).

> Не хотите, — никто не знает, кто что хочет, не правда ли? — чтобы по-Леопольдовому, или по-леопольдовски, Вам же то, или Вам же-с, сделалось предложение-распредложение?

Comment: Принимаю ответ Sharon, но за ваш тоже проголосую.