# А почему запятой нет?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вставная-конструкция, запятая-перед-тире, вопросительный-знак

Уже в справочнике Лопатина нашëл такое предложение:

*Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — какое-то у нее смешное название? — но всё непопадается*.

Почему нет запятой перед первым тире вставки?

Вставка к первой части относится, запятую требует структура второй части — в общем, всë сходится: запятая должна быть перед вторым тире. Но еë мешает поставить вопросительный знак — следовательно, запятая ставится перед первым тире по **[ответу на этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475788/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)**.

Но почему же она не стоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — **какое-то у нее смешное название?** — но всё не попадается.*

Вместо вопросительного знака ставим **запятую** (по аналогии с прямой речью):

*Давно хочется приобрести специальную посудину с суживающимся верхом — **какое-то у нее смешное название**, — но всё не попадается.*

Вставка относится **к первой части**, запятой там нет.

Таким образом, на месте запятой в заданном предложении стоит **вопросительный** знак.

Comment: Почему тогда здесь запятая не поглотилась, а перенеслась со второго тире на первое: _Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, — живы ли, здоровы ли они? — как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах_? Вопросительный знак должен был «съесть» запятую, но почему не «съел», а «сдвинул» к первому тире, где она стоять не должна?

Comment: Тут немного другая модель.  У нас сочинительная связь (союз НО), а там подчинительная. Тоже интересный вариант. Думаю, что придаточное сравнительное сходно с обособленным оборотом, тогда это модель похожа на  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476721/Оформление-вставной-конструкции-у-Чехова   Но нужен собственный анализ именно этого предложения.  Такой системный подход с учетом грамматики более актуален, чем частные решения в каждом случае. А вопросительный знак ничего "не ест", он просто заменяет запятую

Comment: Всë же не понял присутствие запятой в предложении: _Называли фамилии мужей и братьев..._, а вот ответ принять сразу забыл.

Comment: Интересное предложение; при разных решениях получаются разные ответы. Кстати, похоже на симметричную конструкцию. Вставку не относим ни к первой, ни ко второй части, в том числе в устной речи. Сложно найти границу по блокам, непонятен вопрос со структурными запятыми. Вот вам и ответ на ваш вопрос о симметричных знаках – нет смещения!

Comment: Как нет смещения? В приведенном мной смещение к левой. И в последних двух в моем вопросе тоже к левой. А вот в первых двух может и не быть смещения.

Comment: Я про это предложение говорю:  Называли фамилии мужей и братьев...,  Где там структурные запятые  и смещение (решение по вставкам)? Где там граница блоков при решении по блокам?  Если автор не хочет обозначать смещение, то ставит симметричные знаки.