# Оформление вставной конструкции у Чехова

Tags: вставная-конструкция

**Чехов А.П.,**  **рассказ "Мальчики"**

В разных изданиях я видела различные **варианты оформления вставки**. Кроме того, это старая орфография. Как поставить знаки по **современным** правилам?

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша(?) **самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет**(?) сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого.*

Comment: Дополнил. Но без запятых смысл кардинально менятеся.

Answer (score 0):

Так, я считаю:

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша, — самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет — сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого*.

Или так (вариант попроще):

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша (самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет), сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого*.

Обособленное приложение *Катя, Соня и Маша* нужно закрыть. Оформляем либо тире, либо скобками. Запятая ставится перед первым тире, т. к. вставка относится не к приложению, а к подлежащему *три сестры*.

**Дополнено**

Вставка таки может относиться к приложению (я подумал и понял). В этом случае запятую переносим:

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша — самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет, — сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого*.

Если это однородные члены, запятые не ставим (однородные члены: *три сестры, Катя, Соня, Маша*. То есть к подлежащему они не имеют никакого отношения и подразумевается это: *три сестры, а ещë Катя, Соня и Маша*):

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша — самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет — сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого*.

Comment: Возможно.  Я видела перенесенную запятую и  вообще без запятых. Как относитесь к перенесенной запятой или к двум запятым? Структуру  надо обозначать? К какой части  относится вставка?

Comment: Я склоняюсь  к вашему первому варианту, но объяснение у меня другое. Вставка относится к левой части (к сестрам). Остаются вопросы по структурной запятой, и у меня есть версия, как объяснить вариант. Позже дам ответ. Кстати, здесь тема вопроса такая,  как у вас https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475854/Почему-запятая-перед-вставкой-а-не-после  Модели предложений одинаковые, и решение должно быть одно и то же.

Comment: @Sharon Так вам помог мой ответ? Мне первый тоже больше нравится.

Comment: Да, помог. Дело в том, что эту модель я выбрала заранее. И хотела сама составить предложение, а потом нашла  подходящее у Чехова. Но там была другая пунктуация. Вы же выбрали верно, но теперь нужно подобрать очень хорошее оБъяснение.  Тогда этот вариант может стать образцом для других предложений.

Comment: @Sharon Хорошее объяснение? А недостаточно? К прилржению тоже можно отнести. Уберëм подлежащее: _Катя, Соня и Маша — самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет — сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого_. Так тоде можно. Про остальное вроде достаточное объяснение. Но вариант с запятой перед первым тире — где вставка относится к следующей части — представляется наилучшим.

Comment: Максим, вы дали правильный, как мне думается, ответ.  Теперь об объяснении. Вы поняли мое объяснение, вы согласны с ним? Если согласны, то напишите об этом в комментарии под моим ответом, тогда я смогу принять ваш ответ.  А иначе ваше понимание темы остается для меня неясным.

Comment: Чем меня не устраивает ваш ответ. Вы допускаете несколько вариантов. При объяснении выбранного варианта надо работать только с ним, Подлежащее мы не можем убрать, тогда зачем говорить об этом. Нужно ясно сказать, почему запятая не является структурной и не переносится. Вы ведь по Розенталю работаете?

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

Думаю, что правильно напить так:

*Три сестры Володи, Катя, Соня и Маша, — **самой старшей из них было одиннадцать лет** — сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого.*

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Основная структура (**простое** предложение, знаков нет): ***Три сестры Володи** сидели за столом и не отрывали глаз от нового знакомого.*

**NEW!**

**Объяснение первой запятой** при отсутствии второй: почему **не переносится** запятая.

2. **Уточняющий оборот** (обособленное приложение) относится ко  **на второму плану** предложения — условно говоря, это подчиненная **субструктура** (как бы "вложенная" в основную конструкцию).  Если оборот убрать, то предложение будет **простым**.
3. Поэтому запятая перед первым тире **СТРУКТУРНОЙ** (для основной конструкции!) не является и **переносить ее не нужно.**

**РОЗЕНТАЛЬ**

Пункт 4(2): перед первым тире ставится **запятая**, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения:

*Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, **— какой ужас!** — и руки бессильно опустились у него* — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения;

**Объяснение примера**

1. **Без вставки**: *Он посмотрел на пепелище, **которое его окружало,** и руки бессильно опустились у него.*
2. Первая запятая относится к определительному придаточному, к основной структуре всего предложения не относится и поэтому **не переносится.**
3. Вместо второй запятой перед вторым тире союзом И — **восклицательный** знак. Сравнить: *Он посмотрел **на пепелище, **которое окружало его,** — какой ужас, — и** руки бессильно опустились у него*

**Примечание.** Пример с запятой перед первым тире не самый удачный, так как здесь есть восклицательный знак, что осложняет понимание.